# snowflake getting everything except the last part SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

When using snowflake I need everything except the last part of these:

for example1 :

xxx | YYY | XXX | asda | dasd12 | adasda

I just need

xxx | YYY | XXX | asda | dasd12

example2:

32131| Y\ZYY | XXX | asda | dasd12 | 213131 | adsadfd

I just need

32131| Y\ZYY | XXX | asda | dasd12 | 213131

can anyone help me please?
The number of pipes can be random
I need everything except the last pipe and whatever there is after

Comment: We have no idea how your data looks like or which query are you using. Please clarify these points.

Answer (score 1):

there may be prettier ways of doing this but this should work (the functions to use are in caps)

1. REVERSE the string
2. Find the POSITION of the first pipe
3. Get the RIGHT portion of the string from that pipe position
4. REVERSE the result

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string to array, slice it, and stitch it back as string

```
select array_to_string(array_slice(split(your_column,'|'),0,-1),'|')
```

In case you fancy `regex`

```
select regexp_substr(your_column,'(.*)[|]',1, 1, 'e')
```

Comment: the thing is that each time the word is different its not going to be aa or bb

Comment: @Pantzaris That example string is only for example. You're supposed to use your column there